# android how to bring singleInstance activity to foreground when lockscreen is active

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen, single-instance, background-foreground

My application uses a BroadcastReceiver for monitoring charger connection.
When charger is connected the application started.
The main activity defined as singleInstance.
In the BroadcastReceiver i'm using

> it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>                           | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

All working correctly but when lockscreen is active, the activity is "freeze" and neither onCreate nor onStart are being called.

How it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: I"m using :wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, TAG);

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using onNewIntent() implementation.